# Spring boot upgrade from 1.5.x to 2.4.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have updated the spring boot version from 1.5.x to 2.4.4. After updating, when junits are getting executed during build the debug level logs are getting logged. I have used junit-vintage dependency to run junit4 test cases`.

```
Solutions tried,
1) tried setting logging level in application.properties.
logging.level.org.springframework.test=INFO
2) tried setting logging level in logback-spring.xml file.
Nothing worked out. Any help would be great.
```

Comment: Should this `file.logging.level.org.springframework.test` not be `logging.level.org.springframework.test`

Comment: We are not writing logs to a file so I guess this won't affect.

Comment: So what exactly is your question

Comment: @Prashant After updating spring boot version the debug logs are getting logged while junits are getting executed. Need to change it to INFO level. Logs are on console.

Comment: Try using a `logback-test.xml` file in `src/test/resources`.